# How to bind property of child class from itemscontrol of parent class

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have an items control binded to list of parent class. 
I need to bind the properties of the child class in the data template.

These are the classes I have

```
public class Parent {

    private string _name;
     public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _name)) return;
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
}


public class Child1 : Parent{

    private string _prob1;
     public string Prob1
        {
            get { return _prob1; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _prob1)) return;
                _prob1= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Prob1));
            }
        }
}

public class Child2 : Parent{

    private string _prob2;
     public string Prob2
        {
            get { return _prob2; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _prob2)) return;
                _prob2= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Prob2));
            }
        }
}
```

and in my view model I have an observable collection of Parent class

```
 public ObservableCollection<Parent> ParentList { get; set; }
```

and my xaml code

```
 <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ParentList }">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  
              DataType="domainObject:Child1">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Background="Transparent" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Prob1}" Margin="5"HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" />
```

I want to bind the 2. textbox to a property of child class.

Is there any simple way to fix this problem?

Comment: From what you are showing here, your Parent, Child1 and Child2 classes are in no way related to each other. So what exactly are you asking? If Child1 would be *derived* from Parent, your XAML would work as is. As a note, it is pointless to set the DataType property of a DataTemplate that is explicitly used as the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add ": Parent".  Textblock does not contain any value, I thought something is wrong with the binding?

Comment: Please see the answer. Note that a parent/child relationship is typically modelled by composition, not inheritance. In other words, a base (or super) class is usually not called parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `ParentList` collection contains elements of different derived types (either Child1 or Child2) you should have different DataTemplates, which would automatically be chosen by their `DataType` property.

You may declare these DataTemplates in the Resources of the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ParentList}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domainObject:Child1}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prob1}" ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domainObject:Child2}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prob2}" ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```